# Is there a way to open the simple SQL editor in Eclipse by default?

Tags: sql, eclipse, editor

New, SQL Development, SQL File, opens an editor with the intrusive connection window taking up valuable screen space and often serving no purpose. To open without this messiness, one must close the file and reopen from File, Open with, Other, and from list of SQL File Editor, SQL Builder, SQL Editor, choose SQL Editor. Thereafter the file will open with the simple SQL Editor instead of SQL File Editor. Is there a way to get new files to open with the simple SQL Editor by default?

```
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200
Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.4
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with these editors but it may be possible to change the default editor for the file type in the Preferences in 'General > Editors > File Associations'.

Comment: Yes that's the ticket. In File Associations, under File Types, select *.sql, then below select Add... find SQL Editor, Ok, and then select the SQL Editor newly added to the Associated Editors list, and then hit the Default button. It now appears as SQL Editor (default). Apply and Close, and done.

Comment: @greg-449 Make this an answer so I can up-vote you. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Now listed as an answer, by popular demand (albeit one).

I'm not familiar with these editors but it may be possible to change the default editor for the file type in the Preferences in 'General > Editors > File Associations'. – greg-449 Sep 6 at 6:49

Yes that's the ticket. In File Associations, under File Types, select *.sql, then below select Add... find SQL Editor, Ok, and then select the SQL Editor newly added to the Associated Editors list, and then hit the Default button. It now appears as SQL Editor (default). Apply and Close, and done. – chars Sep 6 at 18:53